# FuncAnimation does not iterate over update

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to animate the fitting procedure in a simple linear regression code:

```
def train_model(iter1):
    if iter1 == 5: 
        a.event_source.stop()
    yhat=forward(X)
    loss=criterion(yhat,y)
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(X.numpy(),y.numpy())
    plt.scatter(X.numpy(),yhat.detach().numpy(),s=7,color='r')
    LOSS.append(loss.item())
    loss.backward()
    w.data = w.data - Lr * w.grad.data
    w.grad.data.zero_()
    plt.annotate('n = {}'.format(iter1), [2,27])

fig=plt.figure()
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, train_model, interval=0.001)
```

The problem is the animation only runs the function one time and goes no further than iter1=0, while I expect it to run 5 times.
Thank you for your comments.

Comment: If using `blit=True` you need to return the artists to update. Also, it does not make sense to blit and at the same time clear the axes.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for your comment. I removed blit but still not working.

Comment: In that case try to come up with a [mcve]. (Also, note that interval should be larger than 1, but that should not cause the issue herer)